# Como acceder a las propiedades de un array con laravel

Tags: laravel, array

vengo bloqueado con el siguiente array.

{"id":17,"usuario_id":1,"mails":"[\"hola\",\"Chau\"]","created_at":"2019-11-14 11:02:11","updated_at":"2019-11-14 11:02:11"}

Necesito  mostrar en una vista de laravel en una fila mails: hola y en la siguiente mails: chau. Pero no logro acceder a cada elemento de todas las formas que probé siempre me muestra:

["hola","Chau"]

¿Como puedo acceder a cada una de estas propiedades y mostrarla en la vista de blade?

En el controlador que manda los datos a la vista:

```
public function index()
    {
        $datos = Mails::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
        // dd($datos);
        // dd(json_decode($datos));
        return view('Admin/Cuentas', compact('datos', $datos));
    }
```

En la vista tengo esto:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="col">N°</th>
                          <th scope="col">Usuario</th>
                          <th scope="col">Cuentas registradas</th>
                          <th scope="col">Fecha</th>

                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <?php $i=1; ?>
                        @foreach($datos as $usuario)
                              <tr>
                                <td>{{$i++}}</td>
                                <td>{{ $usuario->usuario_id }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $usuario['mails'] }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $usuario->created_at}}</td>
                              </tr>
                        @endforeach
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Los genero en la vista:

```
<form method="POST" action="/mailsEnviados">
                  @csrf
                  <div class="field_wrapper">
                      <div>
                          <input type="text" name="field_name[]" value=""/>
                          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add field"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></a>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-indigo">Enviar</button>
                </form>
```

Y los guardo:

```
$field_values_array = $_REQUEST['field_name'];
        foreach($field_values_array as $value){

            $mails = new Mails();
            $mails->usuario_id = 1;
            $mails->mails = json_encode($_REQUEST['field_name']);
            $mails->save();
            return 0;
        }
```

Me podrán dar una mano por favor. ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por lo que muestras, en el atributo "mails", no tienes un array, sino un string:

```
{
    "id":17,
    "usuario_id":1,
    "mails":"[\"hola\",\"Chau\"]", // esto es un string, no un array
    "created_at":"2019-11-14 11:02:11",
    "updated_at":"2019-11-14 11:02:11"
}
```

Entonces, para pasarlo a un array puedes usar [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php):

```
json_decode($usuario['mails'], true)
```

Y luego recorrerlo con un foreach:

```
<tbody>
<?php $i=1; ?>
@foreach($datos as $usuario)
        <tr>
        <td>{{$i++}}</td>
        <td>{{ $usuario->usuario_id }}</td>
        <td>
        @foreach(json_decode($usuario['mails'], true) as $mail)
            {{ $mail }}
        @endforeach
        </td>
        <td>{{ $usuario->created_at}}</td>
        </tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

O usar [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.implode.php):

```
<tbody>
<?php $i=1; ?>
@foreach($datos as $usuario)
        <tr>
        <td>{{$i++}}</td>
        <td>{{ $usuario->usuario_id }}</td>
        <td>
            {{ implode(",", json_decode($usuario['mails'], true)) }}
        </td>
        <td>{{ $usuario->created_at}}</td>
        </tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

Con esas dos, se imprimirían todos los elementos de ese array en la misma fila. Pero ahora que releo la pregunta, para imprimir una fila por cada elemento, sería así:

```
<tbody>
<?php $i=1; ?>
@foreach($datos as $usuario)
    @foreach(json_decode($usuario['mails'], true) as $mail)
        <tr>
        <td>{{$i++}}</td>
        <td>{{ $usuario->usuario_id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $mail }}</td>
        <td>{{ $usuario->created_at}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

---

Otro enfoque, con el cual no necesitarías el json_decode, sería castear ese atributo a un array en tu Modelo:

```
/**
 * Los atributos que se deben convertir a tipos nativos.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'mails' => 'array',
];
```

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting

Comment: Sos un genio! muchas gracias me estaba volviendo loco!! funciona todo perfecto!!